# How to redirect all HTTP request to a local web server

Tags: iptables

How to redirect all HTTP request to a local web server, supposing we don't have an internet connections

Exemple

- Web server with @IP 192.168.1.1, running apache
- Client with @IP 192.168.1.X making a HTTP request to X.X.X.X:80-443, and no internet connection is available for always, so all those traffic should be directly redirected to 192.168.1.1:80

I need to do this with iptables, and thank you guys for the help :)

Comment: You can't use dnsmasq?

Comment: Nm, dnsmasq was a bad idea

Comment: I think that if i use dns spoofing, we must to flush the DNS cache of client machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example taken from http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal . This does exactly what you want:

```
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

# Create internet chain
# This is used to authenticate users who have already signed up
$IPTABLES -N internet -t mangle

# First send all traffic via newly created internet chain
# At the prerouting NAT stage this will DNAT them to the local
# webserver for them to signup if they aren't authorised
# Packets for unauthorised users are marked for dropping later
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j internet

$IPTABLES -t mangle -A internet -j MARK --set-mark 99

# Redirects web requests from Unauthorised users to internet webserver
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 99 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1

# Now that we've got to the forward filter, drop all packets
# marked 99 - these are unknown users. We can't drop them earlier
# as there's no filter table
$IPTABLES -t filter -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 99 -j DROP

# Do the same for the INPUT chain to stop people accessing the web through Squid
$IPTABLES -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t filter -A INPUT -m mark --mark 99 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems pretty much what i want to do :)